# Adding variable constraint to linear programming problem

Tags: python, variables, constraints, linear-programming, pulp

I have a question about adding a variable constraint which depends of the chosen value in the solver. My problem is as follows.

I have a set of possible production moments. each production possibility has an amount produced per hour. Also in the same hour there is an demand. the delta of production and demand goes to / will extracted out of the storage.

A certain item has a maximum storage. so the constraint 1 depends on the chosen production moment.

- objective -> minimize the cost of a certain span
- constraint 1-> the storage needs to be above zero and lower than x. x depends of the chosen production moment.

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem. If not, which sort of data needs to be added to make the problem more clear?

Regards,
Floris

Comment: question is clear, but what library you are using? do you heard about lmfit? I really like it to add constrains

Answer (score 2):

This is usually modeled as:

```
inventory[t] = inventory[t-1] + production[t] - demand[t]
0 <= inventory[t] <= capacity
```